# CSS design text-alignment with showing more

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

```css
.read-more-state {
    display: none;
}
.read-more-wrap {
    width: 100%;
}
.read-more-target {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    width: 100%;
}
.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: inherit;
    max-height: 999em;
}
.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
    content: 'Our Story';
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 3px;
    border-spacing: 0.1em;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
}
.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
    content: 'Close';
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 3px;
    border-spacing: 0.1em;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
}
.read-more-trigger {
    padding-left: 450px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #666;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 2;
}
.am-content-container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}
.hcentered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.pure-g {
    text-rendering: optimizespeed;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.pure-g > * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pure-u {
    zoom: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    word-spacing: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.image-row {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
@media only all and (min-width:980px) {
    .grid-sizer, .grid-item {
        width: 16.67%;
    }
}
@media only all and (min-width:980px) {
    .grid-item.col-2 {
        width: 33%;
    }
}
.bot {
    margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
    pointer-events: all;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
}
.text-justified {
    color: #777;
}
h4 {
    padding-left: 50px;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 1.33em;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "pure-g hcentered">
    <div class = "pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-12">
    </div>
    <div class = "pure-u-1 pure-u-md-5-6"></div>
    <h4 class = "text-justified gray">
    <b>Molecular simulations simplified</b>. Macromoltek's mission is to provide easy-to-use scientific software. Our vision is to help researchers make new discoveries                            by keeping the focus on their science.
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>About our products:</b>
    <br>
    <br>
    Macromoltek provides an Online Workspace for Antibody Analysis and Modeling.
    We help researchers analyze potential antibody drug targets. We do this by providing users a web interface to our bioinformatics and molecular modeling software:                           SmrtMol.
    <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-2" />
    <ul class = "read-more-wrap">
        <p class = "read-more-target" style = "list-style: none;"> <br><br>Macromoltek was founded in fall of 2010 by Monica Berrondo (current CEO) to address the                              growing need for easy-to-use antibody modeling software. After overcoming some roadblocks in getting started, she started development of a novel structure prediction                       software package in spring of 2011. Shortly thereafter, Susana Kaufmann (current CFO) joined Macromoltek to help with the                                                                   everyday operations and software development and testing. They worked tirelessly over the next 6 months to develop, test, and                                                               benchmark an algorithm for predicting structures of antibody sequences. This website, www.macromoltek.com was launched at the end                                                           of 2011 as the primary graphical user interface to all of Macromoltek's products and services.</p>
    </ul>
    <label for="post-2" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
    </h4>
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure this out but I have a design flaw in my code and  it has been bugging me.

**The Problem**

When I click the show more item, it shows the text but not in alignment with the previous text.So when I click the show more, it should fill to the width of the ul in h4 but it sets up its own box and not matter what I do the `<p>` with the text inside doesn't want to inherit to the width of the ul parent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
.read-more-wrap {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I use generally ul, ol { padding:0; margin: 0 } and then style the specific ul/ol lately

Comment: glad I could help ;-)